# how can I load facebook button after document loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook

The Facebook button will load at the start of document loaded. But I want to load fb buttons when mouse over div, not at start of document. How can I do it?

And I don't want to use facebook iframe version, as it can not allow me to subscribe to the 'edge.create' event after click like button.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_CN/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
    <!-- 
        when hover box, facebook like button add to this box
        <fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>
    -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.box').mouseover(function (){
        // add facebook like button to .box
    });
```

Comment: Why not just hide the div (with CSS) and show it on hover?

Comment: Why not? I suppose you could use [FB's ASYNC method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (which you should be doing anyway) and use your `mouseover` event handler instead of `fbAsyncInit` though I can't say I've ever tried so YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.box').mouseover(function (){
    $(this).append('<fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>');
    FB.XFBML.parse(this);
});
```

You may need to re-subscribe to edge.create after the parse method.

Comment: This assumes you've called FB.init, since you mentioned using `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(){})`